# How do i sync Xbox 360 Offline Achievement (Not connected to xbox live) that i completed to my xbox live account?

Tags: xbox-360, achievements

Unfortunately i was playing gta 5 story mode campaign and then i finished the "FROM BEYOND THE STARS" Achievement where you had to collect all 50 spaceship parts and after i finished it i noticed that i was disconnected from xbox live and i did not get the achievement but i completed it :(  i even checked my SocialCLub account and the achievement was still locked.
So how can i sync it to xbox live? note that i DID completed the achievement. please help me out! thanks.
also it happened to another achievement in gta 5!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you re-connect to Xbox Live, it will sync the achievements.

However, the date you achieved it will not be recorded, so if you're viewing it on Xbox.com or similar, it will be at the bottom of the list of your achievements for that game, rather than the top.